# Creating Directories using NPM Module fs-extra

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, fs-extra

I need some help.

I need to be able to create a directory structure which looks like the following:

```
parent
  child1
    folder1
    folder2
  child2
    folder1
    folder2
```

I'm currently using fs-extra (npm module). My issue is that the folder structure needs to be read from a .JSON file. When running say buildDir.js, it should read the .JSON file and create the above structure under a dist (distribution) folder. My current .JSON files looks like:

```
{
    "directories": [
        {
            "type": "folder",
            "name": "parent",
            "path": "parent/child1"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

p.s I'm quite new to Javascript so my code my be a little sparse in places.
Any help would be great.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("directories.json", "UTF-8"));
parsedJson.directories.forEach(function(value){
    if(value.type == "folder"){
        fs.mkdirSync(value.path);
    }
});
console.log("It worked!");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If the .JSON file is name directories.json, would the above look like:

    var parsedJson = JSON.parse(./directories.json);

Comment: @sudodashell Edited it to include that.

Comment: it worked! what would be the best way to log it out to the console like console.log("it worked") once all dirs have been created?

Comment: @sudodashell Add the console.log after the foreach.